# Python regex catch groups

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this

```
 string = "2014 Blah - Blah Blah Blah Blah-Blah Blah"
```

I want to get catch groups like this 
  (2014) (Blah) - (Blah) (Blah Blah Blah-Blah Blah)
I tried to do so by this code

```
pattern = "([0-9]{4})(.*)-(\w*)\s(.*)"
search_result = re.search(r'%s'%pattern,string,re.M|re.I)
if search_result:
    print search_result.groups()
else:
    print "Nothing matched"
```

But it is returning

```
('2014', ' Blah - Blah Blah Blah Blah', 'Blah', 'Blah')
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem on your regex:

```
                            v--- Change it to `.*?`
pattern = "([0-9]{4})(.*)-(\w*)\s(.*)"
                       ^-- greedy you have to add `?` to make it ungreedy
```

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\d*)\s(.*?)\s-\s(.*?)\s(.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZ1uW5/1)**

[image]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-4]   `2014`
2.  [4-10]  `Blah`
3.  [12-16] `Blah`
4.  [17-41] `Blah Blah Blah-Blah Blah`
```

Comment: It is working for me but may I know what do greedy and ungreedy actually mean?

Comment: @Goutam You can check a very good **[documentation here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)** about greedyness. Briefly, if you have the string `abcxxxc` and you use this greedy `a.*c` regex, you will match `abcxxxc`, but if you use an ungreedy (or lazy) quatifier like this `a.*?c` then you will match `abc`. Greedy will match as much as it can and ungreedy as less as it can.

Answer (score 0):

Make the first group non greedy:

```
pattern = "([0-9]{4})(.*?)\s*-\s*(\w*)\s(.*)"
```

or

```
pattern = "([0-9]{4})([^-]+)\s*-\s*(\w*)\s(.*)"
```